# Do GORM hook methods work in Grails integration test

Tags: grails, grails-orm, integration-testing

I have simple question

Do GORM hooks method (**beforeUpdate**, **afterLoad** etc) work during **integration** tests? Are they evaluated?

I have integration test (my test class extends **GroovyTestCase**) and as I can see changes that I make in **afterLoad** method on my domain object doesn't seem to work (domain object stays the same after loading) and when I test it manually (run my app) it works (domain object is changed successfully). Also I cannot see any logs or prints to console from hook methods during integration tests.

Is this expected behavior or I am missing something?

Here is some code:
I have PackageState domain object which has field accountID (Integer).
In PackageState I have **afterLoad** hook:

```
def afterLoad() {
        this.accountID = 33333
    }
```

My test suite looks something like this :

```
void "test3"() {
        PackageState packageState1 = PackageState.findByAccountID(11111)
        assertEquals(33333, packageState1.accountID)
    }
```

Message is :
*junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<33333> but was:<11111>*

So seems to me that hook is not called :/ ...

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 3):

You can integration test those event hooks by surrounding the dynamic method (or any other GORM method) by `withNewSession` as:

```
class PackageStateSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    PackageState packageState1

    void "test something"() {
        given:
            PackageState.withNewSession{
                packageState1 = PackageState.findByAccountID(11111)
            }

        expect:
            packageState1.accountID == 33333
    }
}
```

Events will be registered with a new session every time when tested from integration tests.